# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerLib

Tags: ios, swift

Getting this error when trying to build and run my iOS project. It was running fine on a physical device but now trying to run on the simulator it is not working, what does this error even mean?

`Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerLib`

I've tried a
`pod install`
`pod repo update`

but still getting the error

Comment: Hi,
Could you try using AppsFlyerLib via swift package manager to check if the problem exists?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if XCode or CocoaPods version is lower than required, need to upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into the [pod spec for app flyer](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/7/a/c/AppsFlyerFramework/6.8.0/AppsFlyerFramework.podspec.json), you find starting in line 55 that the library excludes the simulator:

`EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]`

So, your library can not be compiled for the simulator, and thus the AppsFlyerLib symbol is missing in your target, i.e. your app.

That is what the error tells you: There is no symbol for the AppsFlyerLib, because it was never compiled for your target.

**How to proceed?**

You will need to use conditional compiles to run your app in the simulator – without AppsFlyerLib of course:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    // Simulator
#else
    // Device
    // import your library here, or use it
#endif
```